# ArgumentException when trying to add a child to Canvas

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, argumentexception

I have some mysterious ArgumentException I have been beating the whole day - still have no idea why does it happen.

I have the next simple method in my MainPage:

```
public void FavsRefresh()
{
    favsCanvas.Children.Clear();

    for (short i = 0; i < (App.Current as App).favUnits.Count; i++)
    {
        FavsItems tmpUnit;
        (App.Current as App).favUnits.TryGetValue((App.Current as App).ids[i], out tmpUnit);
        Canvas.SetTop(tmpUnit.subCanvas, i * 120);
        favsCanvas.Children.Add(tmpUnit.subCanvas);
    }
}
```

Here `tmpUnit` is an instance of my class `FavsCanvas`. Its code doesn't matter - it merges some elements into Canvas, which is called here `subCanvas` and a series of them must be added into parent Canvas, called `favsCanvas`.
The sense in all this, that we have several items initially and the user may delete existing and add new. Every time an item is deleted or added I call this procedure (including initially program loading).
The joke is that it works during loading and when I call it from another pages, but when I call it from class method throws an exception, besides it adds the first element properly and refuses to do that with others.

Every item has unique name, I even tried not to use names at all or use random ones - not a chance. I have no idea why this exception appears?!
I call this method using following:

```
MainPage.MPInstance.FavsRefresh();
```

This way works good from another pages, but from class - fails. I even left only one line (simple reload those items in Canvas):

```
private void FavMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Delete favorite
    if (((MenuItem)sender).Header.ToString() == AppRes.FavsMenuDeleteFav)
    {
        MainPage.MPInstance.FavsRefresh();
    }
}
```

The fun is that this code worked when I wrote it first a couple weeks ago, but now somehow stopped.
Another thing I tried is to make this particular call from a method in App.xaml.cs, which in its turn is called from the class, but it didn't help either.

In fact I have studied most of parameters - everything is the same in both cases: when it works and when not, except the place from where the method is called. But I don't see any proper alternative.

--- added 05 Aug.

I am not sure if it is important, but it always point the next line after the line where exception is thrown:
(the forum does not allow me to post images, so [here](http://postimg.org/image/hdusiml9x/).

I tried to move this method to class both to class itself and to App.xaml.cs - the same problem.

It works properly when is called during loading (my MainPage is Pivot and this page which contains this favCanvas is one of the pivots, but not the first) and when I call it from another page while overriding its OnNavigatingFrom. And when it is called while the the MainPage and this pivot is active. May be something with that?

Comment: At which line this exception occurs?

Comment: At line of addition of a child:
favsCanvas.Children.Add(tmpUnit.subCanvas);

Comment: Way too much typecasting. And TryGetValue returns a `bool`, use it.

Comment: TryGetValue won't help as it gives correct values...

Comment: @Leks you said that "This way works good from another pages, but from class - fails." So... maybe there are several threads are trying to modify `Canvas.Children` collection? I would look in that way.

Comment: It is hardly so. This single method is called from several pages. But even before exeption, it successfully clears all previous cheldren and even add first, but second and all other do not accept. I don't know what to thisk as just can't see any difference between the time it works and the time it don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys, I still can't catch the reason itself, but at last have found a dirty way to walk around.

The page, for some reason, does not like to be modified when it is active (at least this way). So for now I am forced to simply redirect to another page, where I just call my method and then go back.

**If you have some ideas, they are still of demand as my current was is like a crutch and I dislike it**